# LWC passing this into export function stopped working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a util class with the following export function

```
export function fireCustomEvent(component, customEventName,eventValue) {
    let customEvent = new CustomEvent(customEventName, {
        detail: eventValue,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
    console.log('bw: dispatch customEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(customEvent, null, 4));
    console.log('bw: component = ' + JSON.stringify(component, null, 4));
    component.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}
```

I have a component calling this method as such

```
handleSaveSlotClick = (event) => {
    console.log('bw: fire saveslotclick custom event');
    fireCustomEvent(this, 'saveslotclick', { slot: this.editedSlot });
}
```

This code has worked for over a year. However in a new sandbox when executing the code, the event listeners never fire and my console log show the component as {} which is what I suspect is causing the listeners not to fire.

Console output

```
bw: fire saveslotclick custom event

bw: dispatch customEvent: {
    "isTrusted": false,
    "composed": false,
    "detail": {
        "slot": {
            "allowDelete": false
        }
    },
    "type": "saveslotclick",
    "target": null,
    "currentTarget": null,
    "eventPhase": 0,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": true,
    "defaultPrevented": false,
    "timeStamp": 20232.79999998212,
    "srcElement": null,
    "returnValue": true,
    "cancelBubble": false,
    "path": [],
    "NONE": 0,
    "CAPTURING_PHASE": 1,
    "AT_TARGET": 2,
    "BUBBLING_PHASE": 3
 }

 bw: component = {}
```

Anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve?

Comment: Have you enabled Lightning Web Security?

Comment: No that is not enabled, are you saying it should be?

Comment: No, saying it may have impacted behaviour.